Harakat, Tashkeel in arabic, speech to text. Flutter
I am using speech to text in flutter project.  I have a problem, I need to recognize arabic speech to text with harakat, but it's not happening.How do I recognize Arabic with Arabic tashkeel(harakat)?
I tried several libraries on pub
dev but it didn't solve the problem.

Add the speech_to_text and permission_handler package to your pubspec.yaml file:
class SpeechToTextDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SpeechToTextDemoState createState() => _SpeechToTextDemoState();
}

class _SpeechToTextDemoState extends State<SpeechToTextDemo> {
  stt.SpeechToText _speech;
  bool _isListening = false;
  String _text = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _speech = stt.SpeechToText();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Speech to Text Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(_text),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _toggleRecording,
              child: Text(_isListening ? 'Stop Listening' : 'Start Listening'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _toggleRecording() async {
    if (!_isListening) {
      bool hasPermission = await _requestMicrophonePermission();
      if (!hasPermission) {
        return;
      }
      bool available = await _speech.initialize(
        onStatus: (status) {
          print('Speech recognition status: $status');
        },
        onError: (errorNotification) {
          print('Speech recognition error: $errorNotification');
        },
      );
      if (available) {
        setState(() => _isListening = true);
        _speech.listen(
          onResult: (result) => setState(() {
            _text = result.recognizedWords;
          }),
          localeId: 'ar-EG', // Change the locale to Arabic
          listenMode: stt.ListenMode.dictation,
        );
      }
    } else {
      setState(() => _isListening = false);
      _speech.stop();
    }
  }

  Future<bool> _requestMicrophonePermission() async {
    var status = await Permission.microphone.request();
    return status == PermissionStatus.granted;
  }
}


Thank you for your reply. But even with your reply, no solution was found, here is the result: https://ibb.co/V9KkP5s . But I need such a text: https://ibb.co/ss4F0Xn –
Sayfulloh Ismoilov
